# FTPS and certificate authorization on debian

Tags: debian, ftps

I need FTPS with certificate authorization (not login / password). What program to use and how to configure it?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use SFTP with FTP over SSH (using ssh keys, not login/password)

Comment: Documentation requires the use of FTPS.